# Citation reference numbers in parentheses or brackets - a case for this

Tags: citations

Is there a particular case when footnote or endnote reference numbers are to be placed in brackets or parentheses? Is this done in block quotations to distinguish any reference numbers contained in the original source from final citation reference number? To be clear, this refers to the superscripted note number in the text.

Block example below with native citations:

> According to story of the building of Solomon’s temple, the sound of iron tools was not heard.1 No bolts of iron were permitted in the repair of the Publican Bridge across the Tiber as late as the fall of the Roman Republic.2 The first successful cast-iron plow was rejected by New Jersey farmers on the theory that cast iron poisoned the lands and stimulated the growth of weeds.3, [4]

*Footnotes*

1. first native source
2. second native source
3. third native source
4. source of entire excerpt containing all the above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Mechanical" style issues of this kind are going to depend on the place you hope to publish. Say, a magazine, a web site, handed in for credit in a school course, at an engineering office, etc. Try to find out what that place requires. Look at other things that have been published there. Try to find out if they have an official style guide.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please see example added to the post above. The work was originally published in 1954 by OUP, albeit with numerous citation errors. It is part of my task to address this. It would be enormously helpful to locate examples of how other publishers have handled this. I know of just one example, in a publication by The Getty.